# Python Function unable to start: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Tags: python, azure-functions

I created a Python function with "TimerTrigger" template like this:

```sh
func init ProducerFunction --worker-runtime python --docker
func new --name ProducerFunction --template "TimerTrigger"
func start
```

And I am getting this error:

```
[04/23/2020 13:09:09] The listener for function 'Functions.ProducerFunction' was unable to start.
[04/23/2020 13:09:09] The listener for function 'Functions.ProducerFunction' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Settings must be of the form "name=value".
```

SDKs:

```sh
$ func --version
3.0.2245

$ python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value for `AzureWebJobsStorage` in `local.settings.json`. Do not commit this file.

When in production (cloud), this should be set using the Function app settings blade.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{AzureWebJobsStorage}"
  }
}
```

CLI to get the connection string:

```sh
az storage account show-connection-string -g <group> -n <name>
```